# Duplicate records in UFMatch

Tags: database

Wordpress 6.4.2, CiviCRM 5.69.2
Have got the "You have multiple records with the same uf_id in civicrm_uf_match. You need to manually fix this in the database so that uf_id is unique" but the "Learn More" link (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/todo/#todo) leads to a non-existing page.

There are duplicates indeed ( checked using the query below ). But what is the best course of action here?

```
SELECT uf_id, COUNT(*) AS record_count
FROM civicrm_uf_match
GROUP BY uf_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Seeing this in the latest ESR. We're looking into it and will report back with a, hopefully helpful, answer.

Comment: There is the "CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync" ( https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-member-sync )  installed and configured, is it possible there is something not quite right with it?

Comment: We are on Drupal 10 so it's defo data related. We do have member sync installed installed. There is an issue here which could be related: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4500

Comment: @Darren I think this comment deserves to be the answer. And the answer with SQL code piece is perfect as useful comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL will show you the offending records:-

```
SELECT * FROM www_civicrm.civicrm_uf_match
where uf_id in 
(SELECT uf_id FROM www_civicrm.civicrm_uf_match
group by uf_id
having count(*)>1)
```

This should give a list such as:-

```
id, domain_id, uf_id, uf_name, contact_id, language
'667', '1', '180', 'email@example.com', '1234', NULL
'668', '1', '182', 'email@example2.com', '1235', NULL
'669', '1', '180', 'email2@example.com', '1236', NULL
'670', '1', '182', 'email2@example2.com', '1237', NULL
```

So in this case we looked at the User and Contact records (using the Email and Contact ID) to find which one had logged in recently, or made a contribution, event reg, etc.... and removed the ones with older records.

Another option is to update this table with the correct UF_ID and ContactID if the records are valid.

**Please backup your DB when deleting the offending records via SQL.**

Answer (score 1):

I think the big question is going to be *how* you got duplicate uf_ids and how to prevent it from happening. How many duplicates are you seeing? The only fix I can think of is to manually remove the duplicates, but manual database changes can be a little risky. If there are just a few of them, then try to identify the "right" one, and delete the other one. If there are loads of them, I'd say look for a pattern and go from there. In any case, it will probably need to be a manual database fix. Sorry this is sort of a vague answer!

Comment: There is the "CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync" ( https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-member-sync )  installed and configured, is it possible there is something not quite right with it?